# Issue with an audio file from a raw folder

Tags: android, media-player

I want to play an audio file which is there in my /src/res/raw folder as below:

```
 public class SayItActivity extends Activity {
 private ImageButton SayLetterImgBtn;
 private MediaPlayer mp;     
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    SayLetterImgBtn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sayletter);
    SayLetterImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(SayItActivity.this, R.raw.a);   
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }

            });
        }

    });

}
}
```

### Logcat

```
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mds.sayit/com.android.mds.sayit.SayItActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 15:13:16.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 15:13:16.713: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity  com.android.mds.sayit/.SayItActivity
```

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: @nik-I tried creating the object MediaPlayer but I did not see any changes.

Comment: do you have give permission in manifest?

Comment: where you have create folder?

Comment: @nik:I am so sorry nik,I hadn't seen your update.Working perfect:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with ::

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
```

to

```
MediaPlayer mp_xmPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(),
```

**Update ::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called prepare method on media player.

Basically, to use media player, you need to invoke prepare (). media player then prepares media pipeline and notifies the application when it completes preparation. Only then you can call start() on media player.

let me know if this works.

Shash